# Javafx show mouse coords

Tags: java, javafx

I wanted to write simple helper program using `javafx` graphics library.
It should show mouse coordinates of mouse on desktop no matter if the mouse is inside scene or on desktop. I managed to put together this:

```
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

public class Apka extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        new AnimationTimer() {
            public void handle(long currentNanoTime) {

                Text textX = new Text(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX() + "");
                Text textY = new Text(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY() + "");
                textX.setFont(new Font(20));
                textY.setFont(new Font(20));

                HBox root = new HBox(5);
                root.setPadding(new Insets(1));
                root.getChildren().add(textX);
                root.getChildren().add(textY);

                Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 30);

                primaryStage.setTitle("Mouse Coordinates");
                primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            }
        }.start();

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

It works.
Obvious problem I have is that Java program is always on top, I can't switch programs using Alt-Tab windows shortcut. I just want to refresh Text objects and specifically Mouse cords value. Can it be done like this or should I scrap it altogether and go back.

Comment: What do you mean with "alt-tab drawing"? Could you describe a bit more what is happening and when it happens?

Comment: I cant switch programs using Windows Alt-Tab my Java program window is always on top. I assume it is so because i redraw everything every frame. I just want to redraw Text Strings

Comment: Why do you need to create new text fields/scene every time, why not just update existing text fields?

Comment: That is a flag you can set/unset on the stage/window object (e.i. `Stage#setAlwaysOnTop(false)`). Maybe show a bit more code? (Btw this animation timer can be optimized a lot by only updating `textX` and `textY` instead of recreating/populating the Stage and Scene)

Comment: Can i set this flag in any place in the method? edit: tried it but it didnt change any Omg now i see how to put textX and textY into this AnimationTimer

Comment: Post your solution as an answer instead of in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Solved after "optimization":

```
    new AnimationTimer() {
        public void handle(long currentNanoTime) {
            textX.setText(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX() + "");
            textY.setText(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY() + "");

        }
    }.start();

    primaryStage.show();
```

I just needed to update text objects fields with setText() method. Everything else was placed "outside" of AnimationTimer